# Render basic HTML view?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a basic Node.js app that I am trying to get off the ground using the Express framework. I have a `views` folder where I have an `index.html` file. But I receive the following error when loading the web page:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
```

Below is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

You can have jade include a plain HTML page:

in views/index.jade

```
include plain.html
```

in views/plain.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

and app.js can still just render jade:

```
res.render(index)
```

Comment: Just to note that what I want was to serve only one .html file because my app was single page ;)

Comment: This answer is excellent. Note you can also keep using layout and just put the include inside the content block.

Comment: Can We included multiple HTML/JS pages with this method ?

Comment: shouldn't you be able to render that html page without a jade template just for initial testing of express?

Comment: So do we have to create a jade template for each of our HTML files?

Comment: More of a hack rather than a solution.

Comment: As suggested above, this answer only works when using Jade template system. It doesn't work with e.g. handlebars.

Comment: Make sure to install jade i.e. `npm i jade` to use this setup

Comment: One of the easiest approaches is sending the HTML back to the browser.

```
router.get('/about',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/about.html'));
});
```

Or using rendering engines like Pug or Jade. I personally believe that sending the HTML build from frameworks like React.js is the easiest way to achieve rendering of the apps. This https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/ covers most of it.

Answer (score 254):

**Many of these answers are out of date.**

Using express 3.0.0 and 3.1.0, the following works:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

See the comments below for alternative syntax and caveats for express 3.4+:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then you can do something like:

```
app.get('/about', function (req, res)
{
    res.render('about.html');
});
```

This assumes you have your views in the `views` subfolder, and that you have installed the `ejs` node module. If not, run the following on a Node console:

```
npm install ejs --save
```

Comment: why does the res.render require the .html extension in this case but not in the default case with jade.

with the boilerplate code, it just calls

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

but here, it's :
res.render('about.html');

Comment: @Transcendence, I'm not sure exactly. Perhaps you should open a new question.

Comment: With Express 3.4.2: app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: You should use the command 'npm install ejs --save' to update your package.json

Comment: @roland `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` only worked for me (express 3.5.1) when running from within same directory. To run, e.g. via  startup script, I still had to do `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`. Just mentioning in case others have this issue.

Comment: why do you need ejs?

Comment: I currently have `app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`  should I attach another dependency (`ejs`)?

Comment: Everything works but remember about correct path. For me works `app.set('views', '../public/views');` because I have `server.js` and `app.js` in different location.

Comment: Hi, how you pass locals to the view in this case? For example how you handle in 'index.html' this locals.title?: 

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {locals: {title: 'Welcome!'}});
}); I tried ${title} and <%= title%?> but no success.

Comment: Even though this answer is old and it didn't exactly work as described here, I managed to get this to work in a weird way. All the prep work for this answer worked, but when it came to actually rendering a html file, it threw up the same error OP mentioned in his question; Cannot find module 'html.' Then, I realized that regardless of what content is in the file just as long as the file extension is ejs, render procedure renders and client displays it with no errors. So, I changed all of my html files' extension to ejs and they are all being rendered successfully. Horay!!! :)

Answer (score 73):

From the Express.js Guide: [View Rendering](http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#view-rendering)

> View filenames take the form `Express.ENGINE`, where `ENGINE` is the name of the module that will be required. **For example the view `layout.ejs` will tell the view system to `require('ejs')`**, the module being loaded *must export the method `exports.render(str, options)`* to comply with Express, however `app.register()` can be used to map engines to file extensions, so that for example `foo.html` can be rendered by jade.

So either you create your own simple renderer or you just use jade:

```
 app.register('.html', require('jade'));
```

[More](http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#app.register()) about `app.register`.

> Note that in Express 3, this method is renamed [`app.engine`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine)

Comment: Note- app.register has been renamed app.engine in Express 3.

Comment: See answer from Andrew Homeyer. It is the actual answer.

Comment: From some other answer, for Express 4 I ended up using `app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);`

Comment: In express 4, you could also use:    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

Answer (score 62):

You could also read the HTML file and send it:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', 'utf8', (err, text) => {
        res.send(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution is bad because no caching of the files ; it is read for every request.

Comment: its potentially pretty easy to cache it manually. Just store the read file a variable, and only read again, if that variable is blank.
You could also use a JS object and store various files in various variables, with timestamps. Sure its more work than most people would do, but it's good with people new to node. It's easy to understand

Comment: Yikes. This defeats the entire point of convention-oriented, streamlined architectures (like MVC).

Comment: @MarcelFalliere You're assuming that he wants to cache the file, or that he doesn't want to use a custom caching solution. Thank you keegan3d for the answer.

Comment: @MarcelFalliere Then, what is the right solution? I see other answers that requiere new dependencies. Is it necessary just for serve html files?

Comment: @benny @JCarlos the right solution IIMO is to use the `static` middleware of express.

Comment: awesome,I like native node.js API

Comment: I have just one html file because I am using create-react-app and I need to serve the same HTML file for all URLs for react-router to work correctly. This solution seems perfect when I cache the contents in a variable!

Comment: This solution is great for me, thanks~

Answer (score 46):

try this. it works for me.

```
app.configure(function(){

  .....

  // disable layout
  app.set("view options", {layout: false});

  // make a custom html template
  app.register('.html', {
    compile: function(str, options){
      return function(locals){
        return str;
      };
    }
  });
});

....

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("index.html");
});
```

Comment: had trouble with the exact configuration above, so I removed the dot from ".html" and added this: app.set('view engine', 'html'); app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); for a perfect render

Comment: This is a bit weird... you should serve html as static files. This also gives you the benefit of better caching. Creating a custom "html compiler" seems wrong. If you need to send a file from within a route (which you very rarely need to do) just read and send it. Otherwise just redirect to the static html.

Comment: @Enyo this comment seems odd, considering HOW TO do what you are saying should be done is THE QUESTION BEING ASKED, and your answer is to just do it. How do you serve a static html with caching?

Comment: @Tyrsius, well not really. I'm saying that you shouldn't just *render* an html file. If you really really have to send it from within a route you could read the file with `fs` and then send the plain text. What I suggest doing is **redirecting** to the html file instead of trying to directly render it inside the route.

Comment: I see an error on `app.register`. Perhaps it's been deprecated in express 3.0.0.rc3? `TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'register'`

Comment: This suggestion worked for me.  All others seemed to either render the view showing the markup on screen or gave me errors in the node console.  This was the only one that truly rendered the correct HTML.

Comment: @enyo, you missed the point of the steamlined architecture. When the pattern is controller/view (or /processor/view, whatever your specific architecture is), you can't deviate from that with with the obsolete model of extensions. You need to treat your HTML as rendered content like everything else. Keep it DRY, dude.

Answer (score 28):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: sendfile is not cache in production mode so this is not a good solution.

Comment: @SeymourCakes Kindly correct me if I'm wrong, but I think sendFile now supports caching: http://devdocs.io/express/index#res.sendFile

Answer (score 22):

If you're using *express@~3.0.0* change the line below from your example:

```
app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));
```

to something like this:

```
app.set("view options", {layout: false});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I made it as described on [express api page](http://expressjs.com/api.html) and it works like charm. With that setup you don't have to write additional code so it becomes easy enough to use for your micro production or testing.

Full code listed below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.set("view options", {layout: false});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: Why do you repeat `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` after you start the server with `app.listen`?

Comment: what's the diff of serving the html page as static vs. just loading it non-static with express?

Answer (score 15):

I also faced the same issue in `express 3.X` and `node 0.6.16`. The above given solution will not work for latest version `express 3.x`. They removed the `app.register` method and added `app.engine` method. If you tried the above solution you may end up with the following error.

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'register'
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/user1/ArunKumar/firstExpress/app.js:37:5)
    at Function.configure (/home/user1/ArunKumar/firstExpress/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:399:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user1/ArunKumar/firstExpress/app.js:22:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

To get rid of the error message. Add the following line to your `app.configure function`

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Note: you have to install `ejs` template engine

```
npm install -g ejs
```

Example:

```
app.configure(function(){

  .....

  // disable layout
  app.set("view options", {layout: false});

  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

....

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("index.html");
});
```

**Note:** The simplest solution is to use ejs template as view engine. There you can write raw HTML in *.ejs view files.

Comment: Do you have to install `ejs` globally?

Comment: it's tell me it can't find the 'index.html' file

Answer (score 11):

**folder structure:**

```
.
├── index.html
├── node_modules
│   ├──{...}
└── server.js
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(8882, '127.0.0.1')
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div> hello world </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**output:**

hello world

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have to use the **views** directory, Simply move html files to the **public** directory below.

and then, add this line into app.configure instead of '/views'.

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to render HTML file you can use `sendFile()` method  without using any template engine

```
const express =  require("express")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(**path.join(__dirname, 'htmlfiles\\index.html')**)
})
app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log("server is running at Port 8000");
})
```

I have an HTML file inside **htmlfile** so I used path module to render index.html  path is default module in node. if your file is present in root folder just used

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'htmlfiles\\index.html'))
```

inside `app.get()` it will work

Answer (score 8):

For my project I have created this structure:

```
index.js
css/
    reset.css
html/
    index.html
```

This code serves index.html for `/` requests, and reset.css for `/css/reset.css` requests. Simple enough, and **the best part is that it automatically adds cache headers**.

```
var express = require('express'),
    server = express();

server.configure(function () {
    server.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
    server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html'));
});

server.listen(1337);
```

Comment: `server.configure` is deprecated, so directly use `server.use`

Answer (score 7):

To render Html page in node try the following,

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

- You need to install `ejs` module through `npm` like:

  ```
     npm install ejs --save
  ```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Although I tried static option too. Can you explain the mechanism behind it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With Express 4.0.0, the only thing you have to do is comment out 2 lines in app.js:

```
/* app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); */ //or whatever the templating engine is.
```

And then drop your static file into the /public directory. Example: /public/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Express 4.x

- [res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])](https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile)

Send .html files, no template engine...

```js
//...
// Node modules
const path = require('path')
//...
// Set path to views directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
/**
 * App routes
 */
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: app.get('views') })
})
//...
```

```
.
├── node_modules
│
├── views
│   ├──index.html
└── app.js
```

Comment: I had to use 
`var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));`. Without the "../folderName" it was looking in the routes folder.

Answer (score 3):

I added below 2 line and it work for me

```
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Comment: it gives me the following error "Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
"

Comment: @LygubOrg run `npm install ejs --save` in your working directory.

Comment: is it necessary to add a dependency only to serv a html file?

Answer (score 3):

Try res.sendFile() function in Express routes.

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.get('/about',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/about.html'));
});

app.get('/sitemap',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/sitemap.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

Read here : http://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/render-html-file-expressjs/

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to depend on ejs for simply delivering an HTML file, so I simply wrote the tiny renderer myself:

```
const Promise = require( "bluebird" );
const fs      = Promise.promisifyAll( require( "fs" ) );

app.set( "view engine", "html" );
app.engine( ".html", ( filename, request, done ) => {
    fs.readFileAsync( filename, "utf-8" )
        .then( html => done( null, html ) )
        .catch( done );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

---

1)
The best way is to set static folder. In your main file (app.js | server.js | ???):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

public/css/form.html
public/css/style.css

Then you got static file from "public" folder:

```
http://YOUR_DOMAIN/form.html
http://YOUR_DOMAIN/css/style.css
```

---

2)

You can create your file cache.
Use method fs.readFileSync

```
var cache = {};
cache["index.html"] = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/public/form.html');

app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send( cache["index.html"] );                                
};);
```

Comment: not bad! here is a full file demo! [https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/7697d5975bdffe8d474ac19ef906e906](https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/7697d5975bdffe8d474ac19ef906e906)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to set up an angular app with an express RESTful API and landed on this page multiple times though it wasn't helpful. Here's what I found that worked:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         // set the static files location
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));                         // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.bodyParser());                          // pull information from html in POST
    app.use(express.methodOverride());                      // simulate DELETE and PUT
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
});
```

Then in the callback for your api routes look like: `res.jsonp(users);`

Your client side framework can handle routing. Express is for serving the API.

My home route looks like this:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following Lines to your code

1. Replace "jade" with "ejs" & "X.Y.Z"(version) with "*" in package.json file

   ```
     "dependencies": {
      "ejs": "*"
     }
   ```
2. Then in your app.js File Add following Code :

   `app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);`

   `app.set('view engine', 'html');`
3. And Remember Keep All .HTML files in views Folder

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a full file demo of express server!**

https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/7697d5975bdffe8d474ac19ef906e906

*hope it will help for you!*

```js
// simple express server for HTML pages!
// ES6 style

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const app = express();

let cache = [];// Array is OK!
cache[0] = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/index.html');
cache[1] = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/views/testview.html');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send( cache[0] );
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send( cache[1] );
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`
        Server is running at http://${hostname}:${port}/ 
        Server hostname ${hostname} is listening on port ${port}!
    `);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});


app.listen(3400, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at port 3400');
})
```

Put your index.html file in public folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Render index html file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> I am from public/index.html </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now run the following code in your terminal

> node index.js

Answer (score 2):

It is very sad that it is about 2020 still express hasn't added a way to render an HTML page without using `sendFile` method of the `response` object. Using `sendFile` is not a problem but passing argument to it in the form of `path.join(__dirname, 'relative/path/to/file')` doesn't feel right. Why should a user join `__dirname` to the file path? It should be done by default. Why can't the root of the server be by defalut the project directory? Also, installing a templating dependency just to render a static HTML file is again not correct. I don't know the correct way to tackle the issue, but if I had to serve a static HTML, then I would do something like:

```
const PORT = 8154;

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('views'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at port http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

The above example assumes that the project structure has a `views` directory and the static HTML files are inside it. For example, let's say, the `views` directory has two HTML files named `index.html` and `about.html`, then to access them, we can visit: `localhost:8153/index.html` or just `localhost:8153/` to load the `index.html` page and `localhost:8153/about.html` to load the `about.html`. We can use a similar approach to serve a react/angular app by storing the artifacts in the `views` directory or just using the default `dist/<project-name>` directory and configure it in the server js as follows:

```
app.use(express.static('dist/<project-name>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

For plain html you don't require any npm package or middleware

just use this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to allow requests to "/" to be handled by an Express route where previously they had been handled by the statics middleware. This would allow me to render the regular version of index.html or a version that loaded concatenated + minified JS and CSS, depending on application settings. Inspired by [Andrew Homeyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922097/1377016), I decided to drag my HTML files - unmodified - into a views folder, configure Express like so

```
   app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
   app.set('view engine', 'html');
   app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

And created a route handler like so

```
 app.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res){
            if(config.useConcatendatedFiles){
                return res.render('index-dist');
            }
            res.render('index');       
        });
```

This worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

In server.js, please include

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to serve an HTML file which ALREADY has all it's content inside it, then it does not need to be 'rendered', it just needs to be 'served'. Rendering is when you have the server update or inject content before the page is sent to the browser, and it requires additional dependencies like ejs, as the other answers show.

If you simply want to direct the browser to a file based on their request, you should use [res.sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; //Whichever port you want to run on
app.use(express.static('./folder_with_html')); //This ensures local references to cs and js files work

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/folder_with_html/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log("lifted app; listening on port " + port));
```

This way you don't need additional dependencies besides express. If you just want to have the server send your already created html files, the above is a very lightweight way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

- Nowadays we use modules in NodeJS.
- Import packages

```
    import express from "express";
    import ejs from "ejs";
    export var app = express();
```

- Set up the view engine to use the ejs template engine to render files with HTML extension.

```
    app.engine("html", ejs.renderFile);
    app.set("view engine", "html");
```

- Render the HTML file:

```
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.render("index.html");
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually use this

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web'));
});
```

Just be careful because that'll share anything in the /web directory.

I hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

if you are using express framework to node.js

install npm ejs

then add config file

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router)
```

;

render the page from exports module form.js
have the html file in the views dir
   with extension of ejs file name as
`form.html.ejs`

then create the form.js

`res.render('form.html.ejs');`

Comment: What is this mess?