# Express Generator Without Jade

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to generate an express skeleton, using the express generator. 
So it would be this:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
```

However, it adds a bunch of automatic jade files.

I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of those jade files and just using html with the express generator

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try running this command in command prompt:

```sh
express --help
```

It will give you the **express generator help**:

```
  Usage: express [options] [dir]

  Options:

    -h, --help          output usage information
        --version       output the version number
    -e, --ejs           add ejs engine support
        --hbs           add handlebars engine support
        --pug           add pug engine support
    -H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support
        --no-view       generate without view engine
    -v, --view <engine> add view <engine> support (ejs|hbs|hjs|jade|pug|twig|vash) (defaults to jade)
    -c, --css <engine>  add stylesheet <engine> support (less|stylus|compass|sass) (defaults to plain css)
        --git           add .gitignore
    -f, --force         force on non-empty directory
```

<sup>⚡ **Source:** https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html</sup>

The above options give you the list of "view engines".

Now, simply type:

> express -{your choice view engine}

#### For example using `express -e`:

This sets the [EJS](http://ejs.co/) engine as your view handler and removes jade. EJS has the look and feel of HTML with the added ability to inject values via their template system.

Answer (score 12):

If you won't a view engine just type:

```
express --no-view
```

You can add an engine after or not working with server rendering.

Comment: This is what worked for me: `npx express-generator someFolderName --no-view`

Answer (score 3):

You can check the documentation [Express-Generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

As you can see with express -h the view engine suported by express generator are 
(ejs|hbs|hjs|jade|pug|twig|vash), but by deafult jade is suported.

$ express -h

Usage: express [options][dir]

Options:

```
-h, --help          output usage information
    --version       output the version number
-e, --ejs           add ejs engine support
    --hbs           add handlebars engine support
    --pug           add pug engine support
-H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support
-v, --view <engine> add view <engine> support (ejs|hbs|hjs|jade|pug|twig|vash) (defaults to jade)
-c, --css <engine>  add stylesheet <engine> support (less|stylus|compass|sass) (defaults to plain css)
    --git           add .gitignore
-f, --force         force on non-empty directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete the jade files and hook up your own template engine.

For example, I like using Handlebars.js. So in order to use that, in `app.js` or `server.js` or whatever the generator names the main file, you'd substitute the line:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

with something along the lines of this (after installing and requiring handlebars, at least):

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

And every engine is as configurable as you want it o be.

Answer (score 1):

This generator seems to handle EJS templates. EJS is just HTML with the ability to insert variables. Well... Like a templating engine.
But EJS is also the rendering engine for HTML.

In the app.js of the generator you can see this line (15):

```
app.set('view engine', '{views}');
```

So my guess is that if you select the EJS engine when installing, it will be good. As long as you put your html files in the specified folder (line 14, app.js):

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly include your html file into your jade file

```
include ../../public/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your express view engine jade to ejs/ or what ever you like.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

change this line by -

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```