# NodeJS, express: post data from one page to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have to post some data from one page to another page. I am using express with NodeJS.

I have written below code :

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/index.html" );
});

app.get('/RegistrationPage', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/RegistrationPage.html" );
});

app.post('/RegistrationSuccessPage', function (req, res) {
   var uname = req.body.username
   var pwd = req.body.pwd
   var emailAddress = req.body.email
   postData = uname+","+pwd+","+emailAddress
   console.log(postData);
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/RegistrationSuccessPage.html",uname);
});
```

On navigating to "RegistrationSuccessPage", the values of uname, pwd, emailAddress are being printed as undefined.

I have used below code too but it did not helped:

```
app.post('/RegistrationSuccessPage', function (req, res) {
   var uname = req.query.username
   var pwd = req.query.pwd
   var emailAddress = req.query.email
   postData = uname+","+pwd+","+emailAddress
   console.log(postData);
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/RegistrationSuccessPage.html",uname);
});
```

Can someone please help that how I can get values from text boxes and post them on other page.

HTML code is as below:

```
<body>
        <div>   
            <div align="center">
                <label>Please enter below details</label><br><br>
                <label>Username *: </label><input type="username" name="username"/><br><br>
                <label>Password *: </label><input type="password" name="pwd" /><br><br>         
                <label>Email Address *: </label><input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
                <br><br>
                <form action="/RegistrationSuccessPage" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your form must contain all `<input>`s. `<form><div><label><input /></label> ...</div></form>`

Comment: I did that but it does not redirect to other page. Although I can see values in URL.

Comment: You'll also need [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: This helped. Can you please help me with one more query that how can I show this post data on next page ?

Comment: Use `res.render` and a [template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: Is there any other way apart from template engine as I am not using any.

Comment: the only other way is writing your own template engine with `str.replace` or something, so I'd say no there's no other way. [Try `ejs`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495595/using-html-in-express-instead-of-jade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the input fields inside of the form tag. use below code

```
  <body>
    <div>   
        <div align="center">
          <form action="/RegistrationSuccessPage" method="post">
            <label>Please enter below details</label><br><br>
            <label>Username *: </label><input type="username" name="username"/><br><br>
            <label>Password *: </label><input type="password" name="pwd" /><br><br>         
            <label>Email Address *: </label><input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

now try i may work

Comment: I used body-parser and your suggested code, it helped. Can you please let me know how to show this posted data on to next page ?