# viewing site on http://localhost instead of file://, using node.js

Tags: html, node.js, server

I am learning to use node.js.

The site looks fine when run from `file:///C:/.../myfolder/index.html`
I have my jquery and bootstrap files in the directories `myfolder/css/` and `myfolder/js`.

but when I run `node index.js` and go to `localhost:3000`, these css and js files cannot be found.

This is what is in my index.html file:

```
 <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Is there some folder in nodejs that I'm supposed to store these files? Or do I have to put some code in index.js that imports all the css and js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply follow the quick start instructions for Express.js here:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/express

Then browse to `http://localhost:3000` to test

You can use the Atom text editor or Brackets and place your files under the `public` folder and reference them.

http://atom.io
http://brackets.io

By default Express uses a template engine called Jade. You can look here to work with that:

http://jade-lang.com/

[Using HTML in Express instead of Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495595/using-html-in-express-instead-of-jade)

[Node.js + Express without using Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520541/node-js-express-without-using-jade)

Good luck!

Comment: Closest answer! After trawling through express documentation, I found that by adding the line app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); where my css and js folders are in public folder, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your localhost begins in a specific directory on you machine. If you use Xampp, you must put all your server files in C:\xampp\htdocs\ in order to acces these via your localhost URL. Some other servers use a folder called 'www'.

Find your server root path en put your files there. Or create a symlink from your server root to your files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you require the path module?

```
var path = require('path');
```

It's best to create a `public` directory to store your files in.

```
public/index.html
public/css/style.css
public/js/scripts.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you couldn't get access to *localhost:3000/folder/file* is that *localhost:port* is just a virtual port. There is no such directory called *localhost:3000/css/* or *localhost:3000/js*.

To fix this, you need to use express module to configure the root directory from which to serve static assets.

Basically, you need to add the following code:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var path=require('path');    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

and your static files directory will be currentWorkingDirectory/public/, which contains all of your assets.

In your code, to link any source file,

```
href='/fileName.extention'
```

Here is the documentation link [express-static-files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)