# How to configure express.js/jade to process html files?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I would like to configure jade engine to handle .html files in my views folder. Here is my currentserver configuration:

```js
app.configure(function(){
  var pub_dir = __dirname + '/public';
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: nconf.get("site:secret") }));
  app.use(everyauth.middleware());  
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: pub_dir, force:true }));
  app.use(express.static(pub_dir)); 
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(logErrors);
  app.use(clientErrorHandler);
  app.use(errorHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/ejs/index.js

```
app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express);
```

Comment: I get this error:
Error: Failed to lookup view "mobile/index".
If I rename index.html to index.jade, everything works. 
res.render('mobile/index.html', {title:'Home'}); doesn't work either.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was line order. This works:
app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express); 
app.set('view engine', 'html');

Comment: yeah the order can be a freaking nightmare... GladI could help.

Comment: You probably won't see this but thank you. I banged my head off of this problem for 2 days before I found this post. I never realized that the call order would be playing a factor in it not working.

Comment: Just to add in case anyone else comes along, it's important to read the original post's config which is not a "standard config". In particular, note app.use(express.static(..., ...)); I'm saying this because just adding app.engine('.html' ...) and app.set('view engine', 'html') did not suffice in my case like I hoped.

Comment: For some reasons I couldn't get it working successfully with jade. Had to use ejs module `app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);`. See the answer to this related StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862936/express-throwing-unexpected-token-indent/18280946#18280946

Comment: app.engine(".html",require('ejs')._express); This statement throws an error "Error: callback function required". What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you already have `jade` in your `node_modules`

```
npm install --save jade
```

In express 4.x, you can simply set the [`view engine`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings) to `jade`.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
```