# trying to render html files using jade but it still adresses it as a jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

i have read theses two posts regrading my issue:

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046421/how-to-configure-express-js-jade-to-process-html-files
```

and my code is as follows:

```
app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

it is clear that for some reason it is trying to read index as if it was still a jade file and thus i am getting the error. i believe i configured it correct to server a .html file. what is the problem here? i am getting lost...

i have tried to reorder the lines but still same error.

but for some reason i get this error:

```
Error: ....\views\index.html:4
    2| <html lang="en" ng-app="squashApp">
    3| <head>
  > 4|   <meta charset="utf-8">
    5|   <title>Squash Organizer</title>
    6|   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    7|   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

unexpected token "indent"
    at Object.Parser.parseExpr (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:241:15)
    at Object.Parser.parse (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:133:25)
    at parse (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:93:62)
    at Object.exports.compile (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:156:9)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:210:15)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:247:18)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:232:21)
    at View.render (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:505:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\workspace\squash\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:756:7)
```

thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to use jade, have you tried just removing the `app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express);` line?

Comment: Why are you trying to render .html file? It is supposed to be static not dynamic. Either use `express.static` or send the file as is.

Answer (score 4):

With this line:

```
app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express);
```

You told express to render templates ending with `.html` using jade.

With this one:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

you told express that it should interpret template names without extension as ones ending with `html`.

So my guess is that you're trying to render `'index'`, express interprets it as `index.html` and then passes to jade as it was instructed to do.

It's better to map jade to it's own extentension (`.jade` is an obvious candidate). And render your `index.html` using it's full name.

1. Add [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) to your project:

   ```
   var engines = require('consolidate');
   ```
2. Tell jade to render stuff ending with `.jade`.

   ```
   app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
   ```
3. Register simple html renderer for stuff ending with `.html`:

   ```
   app.engine('html', function(str, options) {
      return function(locals) {
          return str;
      };
   });
   ```
4. Tell express to render templates with no extension as jade:

   ```
   app.set('view engine', 'jade');
   ```
5. Use this to render your index:

   ```
   res.render('index.html');
   ```

   and this:

   ```
   res.render('view-name-without-extension');
   ```

   to render jade template.

Comment: i didn't really understand what should i do. could you further explain please?

Comment: You have to run "npm install Consolidate". Resulting edit on my end, tested ..

    `/* further up */ var engines = require('consolidate'); 
    /* then later */ 
    app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
    app.engine('html', function(str, options) {
       return function(locals) {
           return str;
       };
    });
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 1):

By Default express takes Jade template engine. Your app.js should look like this.

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); // <<<---- CHANGES FROM EJS TO JADE !!!
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: The only thing different here is the switch from ejs to Jade, correct?