# How to render html via routing instead of jade

Tags: html, express

In my nodejs app I need to render html files. The view engine is currently set to jade but I am not using this format.

I need it set so that i can render the relevant html page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a view engine to serve HTML. Instead, just use the static middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: so if my views sit under the app/views folder would the /public needs to be changed to /app/views?

Comment: No joy i get the following error 500 Error: Failed to lookup view "views/admin/users.html. I have tried to use consolidate.js following this example but still no joy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210532/trying-to-render-html-files-using-jade-but-it-still-adresses-it-as-a-jade. My engine is  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app'))); Within app there is a view folder