# express3 - trying to route files

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to route files in express3 but I get a problem.
So here is the code for routing the files -

```
var app = require('express')(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index/index.html");
    app.use(app.static(__dirname + 'index'));
});
```

When I open `localhost:8080` in Chrome it gives me an error :
`TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'static'`

What I did wrong?

All of my HTML/CSS/JS files are in the index directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render basic HTML view in Node JS Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` is static function from express, you cannot access it from instance object crated by express. you need to assign required express to different variable.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index/index.html");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'index'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! and your English and explanation are great ;)