# "Error: Cannot find module html" when visiting HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I started my application, and visited `localhost:8333` in my browser, it threw an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at new View (C:\Users\fr\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:42:49)
  at Function.app.render (C:\Users\fr\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:483:12)
  at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\fr\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:755:7)
  at allClients (C:\Users\fr\node_modules\apps\chat.js:13:7)
  at callbacks (C:\Users\fr\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
  at param (C:\Users\fr\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
```

Here's my code:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');

var app = express(),
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(app),
socket = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('./test.html');
});

server.listen(8333);
```

This is my project folder structure:

```
node_modules/
    express/
    socket.io/
    apps/
        chat.js
        test.html
```

This is my new `app.configure`:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

But that code fails with this error:

```
path is not defined
```

Comment: Do not place your code inside node_modules! The folder contains dependencies and should be inside your application's folder.

Comment: I thought that all my modules files must be in the root folder ?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I am assuming that `test.html` is a static file. To render static files, [use](http://expressjs.com/api.html) the static middleware like so:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This tells Express to look for static files in the public directory of the application.

Once you have specified this, simply point your browser to the location of the file and it should display.

If, however, you want to *render* the views, then you have to use the appropriate renderer for it. The list of renderers is defined in the [consolidate.js library](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js).

Once you have decided which library to use just install it. I use `mustache` so here is a snippet of my app file:

```js
var engines = require('consolidate');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

This tells Express to—

- Look for files to render in the `views` directory
- Render the files using `mustache`
- The extension of the file is `.html` (you can use `.mustache` too).

Comment: No problem.Hope you enjoy node js like I do!

Comment: I have used it for a chat 2 years ago ! I liked it !

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`  This might be a little confusing to some people.  Don't point the browser to the `/public` directory.  Point the browser to the `/` root directory and it will find the static files located in the `/public` directory.

Comment: Beautiful Answer :)

Comment: so does that mean expressjs has no default rendered for HTML?

Answer (score 34):

A simple way is to use the EJS template engine for serving `.html` files. Put this line right next to your view engine setup:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for a short answer! All I needed was that single line of code to fix the error.

Answer (score 13):

Install the [`ejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) module from npm:

```
npm install ejs
```

Then just paste below two lines in your main file (`app.js` or `main.js`):

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

Install `consolidate` and `mustache` by executing the below command in your project folder.

```
sudo npm install consolidate mustache --save
```

And make the following changes to your `app.js` file

```
var engine = require('consolidate');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', engine.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

And now HTML pages will be rendered properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to declare a view engine. If you want to use a view/template engine:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

or

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

But to render plain HTML, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express).

Answer (score 2):

Use `res.sendFile()` instead of `res.render()`. What you're trying to do is send a whole file.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the [`html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html) module from npm:

```
npm i html
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Incorrect, html doesn't provide an engine.