# React engine is causing "Cannot find module" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, url-routing, react-engine

I'm using [`react-engine`](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine) to supply the server with access to react components. With `react-engine` you can feed an `express` react by routing a url and using res.render. To do this you need to provide a path the docs specify `req.url`.

```
app.use("/", function(req, res){
    return res.render(req.url, data);
})
```

Now when the url is `/index` that will be passed into [`react-router`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) and the react route will be compiled into a string as returned at that endpoint.

The issue I'm having is when the url has a period.

Whenever there is a period in the get query (`/index.html`) or the route path itself (`/index?example=foo.bar`) I get an error stating the following.

```
Cannot find module 'html'
```

or

```
Cannot find module 'bar'
```

respectively.

Do I have to escape periods to the url?

```
res.render(req.url.replace(/\./g, ""), data)
```

How can I get rid of the `Cannot find module 'extension'` message?

I also put [a specific issue here](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/issues/52) in `react-engine` on github.

Comment: I'm digging into this and I think it might have something two do with teh express view engine [here](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/blob/master/lib/expressView.js#L23). The error occurs when any route contains a period: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111386/node-js-cannot-find-module-html

Comment: I think its happening because `express/lib/view` thinks that the file being passed is a normal view template like `index.jade` and what it does is parses the extension to find what templating library it is using https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/view.js#L76-L79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put up a PR on react-engine a while back.

https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/pull/58

There's also a long-running issue open here:

https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/issues/52