# Nodejs Express - folders inside public folder not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have created one nodejs application using express to serve my portfolio and my projects. My portfolio is working fine when root is accessed "/" but when i serve my projects like "/FootballScores" and "/FacebookGrabber", one is working half(means all angular files loaded successfully but still it displays nothing) and the other project is not loaded and it shows error :

> "Error: Cannot find module 'html'"

Also I have installed all the npm packages. Here is the app.js code:

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
xoauth2 = require("xoauth2"),
path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("index.html");
});

app.get("/FacebookGrabber", function(req, res){
res.render("FacebookGrabber/index.html");
});

app.get("/FootballScores", function(req, res){
res.render("FootballScores/index.html");
});

app.listen(3000, process.env.IP, function(){
console.log("Portfolio Server Started!");
});
```

I think the problem is because of incorrect public path... What can i do so my projects /FootballScores and /FacebookGrabber also gets loaded correctly?

Comment: Portfolio is served correctly on root "/", FootballScores is working half same as before, and on "/FacebookGrabber"  this text appears : "FacebookGrabber/index.html" instead of "Error: Cannot find module 'html'"

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111386/error-cannot-find-module-html

It seems there is an issue trying to use both `express/static` and `render` at the same time without an engine.

Comment: Sorry bro, it was my mistake when i copied FacebookGrabber Folder it was empty, there was no index.html file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Common mistake, no worries

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, it was my mistake when i copied FacebookGrabber Folder it was empty, there was no index.html file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your view engine to html before your `res.render` calls?

```
// View engine
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```