# How to set the build environment using Node.js and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I've created a build environment using express JS. But, I got into trouble to configure AngularJS view -- Pleas help me to fix this issue..

## 1:

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
// view engine setup
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//res.render('dist/index.html');
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);


//Trying to setup my view over here -- dist folder is holding the index.html file 

app.set('views', __dirname + '/dist');
app.set('view engine', 'html');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/dist/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('./dist'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

httpServer.listen('8080');
console.log("server is started");
```

Above build setup was throwing following error ::

Error : Can't find module 'html' -- I'm not sure how to configure Node.Js to refer the angular JS veiw and all the injuctors..

Comment: Ok, what your application should do? Serve static content, right? (such as html/css/js files) Is that the only goal for now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

You are trying to specify view engine with html value, which is not a view engine (expressjs tries to require html module internaly, but doesn't find it). If you need to serve just html files without templating use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And move all files you want to serve to public folder.

**UPD:** you can actually require html file from jade

> in views/index.jade
>
> ```
> include plain.html
> ```
>
> in views/plain.html
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> ...
> ```
>
> and app.js can still just render jade:
>
> ```
> res.render(index)
> ```
>
> [Andrew Homeyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922097/2866570)

References:

- http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.engine
- [How do I use HTML as the view engine in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express)
- http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. But, I'm still not able to do a setup.. I'm still missing something.. Please advise me..