# How to link css to html in an express project?

Tags: html, css, express

I have an Express.js project wich looks like this:

- public

  - images
  - javascripts
  - stylesheets
- routes

  - index.js
- views

  - authentication.html
  - authentication.css

In **routes/index.js** I can display my html file like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../views/authentication.html'));
});
```

But the file is displayed without its style contained in `authentication.css`.
However, `authentication.css` is linked to `authentication.html` :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "authentication.css">
</head>
```

I tried to move my `.css` to the public/stylesheets folder and change the `<link>` tag to point to the new location but it didn't worked.

**What am I supposed to do to apply my css files to the corresponding html files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found some sort of solution thanks to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911882/5016201 .

I just added this line in `app.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'views'));
```

It displays my html + css files correctly, I don't know if it is a good practice but it is good enough for what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but try using: =

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="authentication.css">
```

try not using whitespace.

u can also try going to the route first (based on the list above)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../views/authentication.css">
```

When it is being run it might be using the JS as the default directory so if the first answer dont work use second

let me know if it works :D