# Express js render : TypeError: this.engine is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting TypeError: this.engine is not a function. I don`t know why I am getting this error. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

My server file:

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');

var app = express();

//configure app
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Ready on port 1337');
});
```

And my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div>Hello Express</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I get the error

> 

[image]

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.html",
    "directories": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "mehadi",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.13.0",
        "html": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "(github.com/mehadi07/Random.git)"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "description": ""
}
```

I installed the `html` engine via

```
npm install --save html
```

Comment: What's your `package.json`? Where are you registering this `'html'` view engine, and what engine are you registering?

Comment: What template engine you're trying to use ? I don't recognize `html`-template engine. Have you installed the engine (with `npm`) ? Please RTFM: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "mehadi",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.13.0",
    "html": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "(https://github.com/mehadi07/Random.git)"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}

Comment: i used npm install --save html

Comment: @MdMehadiHasanMozumder: To improve the question, add details, etc, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Comment: Please note that https://www.npmjs.com/package/html is not express related in any way. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`html` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html) you've installed is unrelated to Express. So it's not surprising that if you tell Express to use it, it fails.

If you're looking to serve static HTML files, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express), and the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). The simplest way is just

```
app.use(express.static('views'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit and reply.

Answer (score 1):

[html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html) package is not a template engine that can be used with Express. Instead it is a *HTML pretty printer CLI utility*.

Please see [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) for a list of template engines that works fine with Express.