# Use `index.html` rather than `index.ejs`

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, ejs, viewengine

I have a `mean-stack` application. By going to `https://localhost:3000/#/home`, it reads `views/index.ejs`. Here is the setting in `app.js`:

```
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.ejs', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Actually, I don't use the feature of `ejs` in `index.ejs`. So now I want to use just a `index.html` rather than `index.ejs`.

I put the content of `index.ejs` in `public/htmls/index.html` and `views/index.html`. And here is the current setting in `app.js`:

```
var app = express();
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
    // res.sendFile('index.html'); // does not work either
});
```

However, running `https://localhost:3000/#/home` returns

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Edit 1:** by following the answer of `user818510`, I tried `res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'views') });` in `app.js`, it still can NOT find `index.html`.

Whereas, in `routes/index.js`, the following can find `index.html`, but it gives a warning `express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead routes/index.js:460:9`.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
... ...
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html'); // works, but a deprecation warning
    // res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'views') }); does not work
});
```

It is really confusing...

Comment: If you dont want to use ejs, and only want to use html, then try serving these files as static content

Comment: Try `app.set('view engine', 'html')`.. Sorry  here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express

Comment: It gives `Error: Cannot find module 'html'`

Comment: It sounds like you're using `res.render()` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single page mean application, then you only need to start *express* with *static* and put `index.html` in `static/` dir :

**Project layout**

```
static/
  index.html
server.js
```

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

var server = app.listen(8888, function () {
  console.log("Server started. Listening on port %s", server.address().port);
});
```

Now you can call `http://localhost:8888/#home`

Comment: It's only an example... Any url can be called. Using `#` or not is up to you, With angularjs it's called html5mode https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the path. Your `index.html` is located at `public/htmls/index.html` and `views/index.html`. Your `root` option in `res.sendFile` should be `__dirname`+`/public/htmls/` or `__dirname`+`/views`

In your code, you are using the path:

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
```

Your `app.js` would be in the project root where you have `public` directory alongside at the same level. Based on your `root`option in `res.sendFile`, you would have to place `index.html` at the same level as your `app.js`.

You should change the root path in res.sendFile. Use:

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'htmls') });
```

OR

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'views') });
```

The above `root` is based on the path that you've mentioned in your question.

Here's the link to the docs:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Your no default engine error is probably because you have commented the line where you set the view engine to ejs but still have existing ejs views. Uncommenting that line with the root path change should solve your issue.

Comment: @SoftTimur Does it work when you remove the `root` option in `res.sendFile` and specify the absolute path for `index.html`?

Comment: Both `res.sendFile('./views/index.html')` and `res.sendfile('./views/index.html')` return a `404` error.

Comment: @SoftTimur I meant using the full absolute path. Something like `/home/test/yourapp/views/index.html`. To check this, you'll also need to remove the root option.

Answer (score -2):

Do not serve static content from an application server.

Use a web server for that, and in production, a content delivery network like Akamai.

A content delivery network will charge you per bandwidth (e.g: 10 cents per Terabyte). Serving the equivalent of 10 cents in Akamai can cost you thousands of dollars using cloud instances.

In addition to that, your servers will have unnecessary load.

If you absolutely have to serve static content from your application servers, then put a reverse proxy cache like nginx, varnish or squid in front of your server. But that will still be very cost inefficient. This is documented in the [express website](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html).

This is common practice in every Internet company.