# Angular js Expressions not working in Node js project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have configure node js default project with express and using HTML page instead of JADE. I want to use Angular JS within HTML pages. Angular JS Simple examples are working fine in this project as :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Its working Fine. But if i am using {{name}} instead of  ng-bind="name", its not working in this project.
For Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is not working in node project. Can anyone help me to find-out the issue.

App.js File code is as following:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Sql server new code 
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var webconfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '#####',
    server: '######',
    database: 'Test_Training',

    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
    }
}
var sql = require('mssql');
// Sql server new code 

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();


// To use simple html page
var cons = require('consolidate');

// view engine setup
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
// To use simple html page

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: where is the controller

Comment: It works correctly for me.

Comment: @sachilaranawaka this code is working without controller

Comment: @Hadi yes you are right. Its working fine in simple html page.. But not working in My node js project. I am unable to find out the issue.

Comment: what display in console?

Comment: @sachila ranawaka I want to only print input at run time for simple test. These are not working.Once these works then i move forward.

Comment: @Hadi No error shown in console also.

Comment: Are you using view engine ? Can you provide some code in server ?

Comment: @ThanhTùng \{{name}} also not working. I am using app.set('view engine', 'html') in app.js to view engine settings.

Comment: If you use html you dont need set view engine . Try remove it

Comment: Above HTML code is not belongs to JADE syntax. Please Change view engine or place JADE syntax https://www.clock.co.uk/insight/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus

Comment: @ThanhTùng i have comment the line of view engine , Now its showing error.. "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided." I think it is mandatory.

Comment: No it's not mandatory

Comment: @ThanhTùng Please suggest me how to remove engine.

Comment: try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html engine is not supported out of the box.

(ref: https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines)

Solution given by @Thanh Tùng will work, but if you really want to set html as a view engine you should follow this solution

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// Set EJS View Engine
app.set('view engine','html');
// Set HTML engine
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Later you need to place your index.html inside /views directory

(original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945104/3627827)

EDIT: updated answer as suggested by @DanielZiga

Comment: is like he said: My Moto isn't working and you are suggesting to buy a bike... while, instead, he's expecting to fix the issues!

Comment: Well, he said that he wants to use html view engine, so he does not care what tool will he choose. If the moto is broken down, why not use a bike? Also this moto's build is failing. Do you think it's safe to ride a moto with it's screws loosen? ;)

Comment: It is commonly accepted that a good answer is a pertinent answer... If I wish to taste apples, I don't care that strawberries taste better. I want apples, if you don't have apples, then, you can't solve my issue... Otherwise, you could have suggested to build everything in `C++` to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

First remove it :

```
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

I'm not sure about your strug folder but I guess file index.html of you in folder public . Try add this code in your node :

```
   app.get('/*',function(req,res){
          res.sendFile( index.html,{root:path.join(__dirname,public/index.html)});
        })
```

Comment: Tung i have Update the App.js code into my question part. Can you please modify this where you suggest me add this code. I have tried but its showing error. "unexpected syntex"

Comment: @ThanhTùng you are still missing an ' in first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`Swig`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig) as a `Template Engine` for your Server Side Rendering.

As you can see in its doc, Swig uses `{{` and `}}` as interpolation delimiters... they're the same used by AngularJS.

What could happen is that `Swig` doesn't let your raw html reach the angular...

Try to change [`interpolation delimiters`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider):

```js
// https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

angular
  .module('ModuleName')
  .config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {

    // set start symbol here
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('^_^');

    // set end symbol here
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('"_"');
  }])
;
```

Comment: in which file these chnages to be made??

Comment: anywhere... Try to don't use SO as debugging help social media.

Comment: @Hitmands you are lacking $ inside 'interpolateProvider', also you didn't specify where to put that code. (Notice that there's no js file attached)

Comment: While it's true that Swig is set as view engine, [consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/) swig is no longer maintained (and it's build is failing), so I'd suggest against using it.

Comment: @Hitmands after using this its showing "[$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=ModuleName" error

Comment: As I said, SO is not a debugging help place. Instead of uncritically copy/past code, you should try to understand the code... `ModuleName` should be the name of the root module in your application.