# Different ways to render static assets using express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Which of the following method is preferable to render the static assets. Consider that only helpPage.html is the only file exist in the `public` directory

Method 1:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Method2:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
   res.render(__dirname + '/public/helpPage.html');
})
```

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911882/5200242).

Answer (score 0):

If helpPage.html is the only static file you will deliver, I propose a third option:

```
app.get('/helpPage.html', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/public/helpPage.html');
});
```

I don't see the purpose of using app.use here.

Additionally you may want to use path.join:

```
const path = require('path');
app.get('/helpPage.html', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile( path.join(__dirname, '/public/helpPage.html') );
});
```

This ensures that the paths are properly joined regardless of what machine you are running on.

Comment: Personally I would use `res.sendFile` rather than `res.render` here. Otherwise I agree

Comment: I went back and checked the api documentation. I agree, sendFile is better suited for this instance