# Express incorrectly renders HTML

Tags: javascript, express

[How do I use HTML as the view engine in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express)  after studying the link I started server with an index.html file at port 8001. However it doesnot renders correctly saying in console:

```
Server Started
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token !== in file /home/bereznyak/Рабочий стол/restplatzproject/views/index.html.
```

I use in my html some handlebars.js notations which cause this error. My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="item_card">
            <div class="restaurant_name">
            <p>Empfang restaurant: <span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[0]}}</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="updated">
              Updated at: {{cellsArray.[1]}}
            </div>
            <!-- этот div скрыт, причины описаны в js.js файле, копия этого diva' в следующем div'e -->
            <div style="display: none" class="places_number">
            <p> <span class=" getme places_number_from_google decorated">{{cellsArray.[2]}}</span> Places.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="places_number">
              <p> <span class="places_number_js"></span> Places.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="discount">
            <p><span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[3]}} %</span> your Discount</p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
              <p>Discount valid from <span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[4]}}</span> till <span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[5]}}</span> </p>
            </div>
            <div id="button" class="button" onclick="displayDiv()">
                <form action="/pay" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

How can I still overcome this error as I dramatically need these handlebars.js expressions?

Comment: Read this https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars. It may help you

Answer (score 0):

After reading [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars#extnamehandlebars)

I found such code:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

it means we can change `extname` from `.hbs` to `.html`:

```
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('.html', exphbs({extname: '.html'})); // defining view engine for file extension 
app.set('view engine', '.html'); // defining default extension
```

don't forget to install package:

```
npm i --save express-handlebars
```

Comment: `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));` my next line of code which results in: **Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/home/bereznyak/Рабочий стол/restplatzproject/views"** What's wrong about it?