# Use Nodejs with already made HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I just started learning Nodejs and I want to use it to handle server side code on my site such as a Log In system

I have a `login.html` file with the following code, and a `CSS` file referenced to style this page. Here's the `HTML` form:

```
        <div id="login">
            <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="" method="post">
                <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required><br>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
                <input id="enterBtn" type="submit" name="enter" value="LOGIN" onClick="contactForm(this.form)">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Everywhere I've looked so far it seems that I have to use `.ejs` files in order to communicate with my `server.js` script.

But when I try copy/pasting my `login.html` code into a `login.ejs` file, but:

1. my css doesn't work anymore
2. when I ***ahref*** my `login.ejs` page from an html page, instead of opening the page, it opens the `login.ejs` code in the browser instead. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: yes, I'm using express

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express