# NestJS - Cannot find module 'html'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I get an error when I try to render a simple static html file (no template). I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I tried a bunch of things but without success.

### *src/modules/app.module.ts*

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AppController } from './app.controller'
import { AppService } from './app.service'
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module'
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static'
import { join } from 'path'
import { DiscordModule } from './bot/discord.module'
import { UserModule } from './database/user/user.module'
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { ConnectionOptions, getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm'
import { RoleModule } from './database/role/role.module'
import { AppConfigModule } from './config/config.module'
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport'

@Module({
  imports: [
    AppConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      envFilePath: [ '.env.local', '.env' ],
      expandVariables: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () =>
        Object.assign(await getConnectionOptions(), <Partial<ConnectionOptions>>{
          autoLoadEntities: true,
          cache: true,
        }),
    }),
    UserModule,
    RoleModule,
    DiscordModule,
    AuthModule,
    PassportModule.register({
      session: true
    }),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public'),
      exclude: [ '/api*' ],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [ AppController ],
  providers: [ AppService ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### *src/modules/app.controller.ts*

```js
import { Controller, Get, Render } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AppService } from './app.service'

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
  
  @Get('/hello')
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello()
  }
  
  @Get()
  @Render('index.html')
  root() {}
}
```

### *src/main.ts*

```js
import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core'
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AppModule } from './modules/app.module'
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express'
import { AppConfigService } from './modules/config/config.service'
import { AuthenticatedGuard } from './modules/auth/auth.guard'
import session from 'express-session'
import { TypeormStore } from 'connect-typeorm'
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm'
import { SessionEntity } from './database/entities/session.entity'
import { SESSION_SECRET } from './modules/config/config.constants'
import passport from 'passport'

async function bootstrap() {
  const app    = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule)
  const config = app.get(AppConfigService)
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())
  app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthenticatedGuard(app.get(Reflector)))
  app.use(session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    secret: 'djsnjfjknskjfnanfkdfalsndjfndsj',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new TypeormStore().connect(getRepository(SessionEntity)),
  }))
  app.use(passport.initialize())
  app.use(passport.session())
  app.enableCors({
    origin: [ config.baseUrl ],
    credentials: true,
  })
  app.setViewEngine('html')
  await app.listen(config.port)
}

bootstrap()
```

### Stacktrace

```
[Nest] 192424   - 2021-05-23, 6:07:20 p.m.   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot find module 'html'
Require stack:
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/dist/main.js +3532ms
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
Require stack:
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
- /home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/dist/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at new View (/home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at ExpressAdapter.render (/home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:30:25)
    at RouterResponseController.render (/home/drunkenponey/projects/the-4-horsemen/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-response-controller.js:27:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just serving regular HTML, not using template engines, you don't need to call `app.setVewEngine()`. Just set up your static directory and you'll be good to go. [You can read more about this in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911882/9576186)

Comment: The thing is that I don't want the user to be able to see/download these static files without being authenticated and the only way I found to ensure the user is authenticated is to *render* it from a controller's endpoint (in this case the `root()` function of *app.controller.ts*). However, if I do not specify a render engine I get a `no default engine specified` error.

Comment: `render` isn't supposed to be used if you aren't using a rendering engine. You should use `sendFile` instead to send back a static file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Render('index')` instead of `@Render('index.html')`