# MEAN stack, I don't want to use Jade, how do I just use HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I am developing an application with the MEAN stack and am really not liking 'Jade'. I find myself just using an HTML to Jade translator a lot and would just rather write in HTML.

How do I not use Jade in an Express project?

Also, could someone explain what a templating engine is and why one is needed?

Comment: You're asking too many questions here. Please make this more specific. Research templating engines on your own first instead of just spitting out the question on SO.

Comment: Check out spectrum's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express#answer-6960021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

in your config file instead to use just vanilla HTML.

As the previous response, templating engines allow you to set more dynamic content and write less code.

Comment: then in my 'views' folder I can just use index.html instead of index.jade?

Comment: @Tim see my comment on your question. In short, no, this will just serve static pages from the `public` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try `EJS` as it looks much more like HTML.

http://embeddedjs.com/

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

You can render out HTML through the response object `res.send` and generate all the HTML in server side code

```
res.send('<html>...</html>');
```

Generally if you're displaying dynamic data rather than a static HTML page, people find it easier and more encapsulating to use a view engine such as EJS and bind the view to an object that contains all the dynamic data they want to display. This is an example of applying the `Separation of Concerns` design principle, which is considered good practice:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: While using `ejs` works, it's also both the evaluative and filesystem overheads of installing a module that ultimately doesn't contribute much.