# Loading html page in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http

How can I load a HTML page using NodeJs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should load data from an html page.

```
var http = require('http');
http.get('http://www.google.com', onGotData);
function onGotData(res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on('data', onGotData);
  res.on('end', onEnd);
  function onGotData(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  }
  function onEnd() {
    console.log(chunks.join(''));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using to render the page. If you are using AngularJS for the front end, send your HTML as a string or with `sendfile()` method of express middleware. Basically node and express are used to call rest API to get your HTML as a string and render with AngularJS.

e.g

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));

app.all('/homePage', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('home.html');
});

app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Here, index HTML is angular single page application with ng-view directive. Render all the HTML at client side which you get from the server.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newangular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newroute1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ParentController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/clintSIdeRoutes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="schoolApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"><span class="col-md-12"><h1>Header Goes here</h1></span></div>
        <div ng-view></div><!-- this is place where your html is rendered --> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the link:

```
https://github.com/bharat-daffodilsw/school
```

This is my first attempt at sharing apps. Hope this helps. Currently, I am working on it when I have free time. So it's not complete but works fine.

Answer (score -1):

User [express](http://expressjs.com). Follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express)

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();
app.register('.html', require('jade'));
//app.engine for version 3


app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));
//place your html in public folder beside the app.js

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index.html');
});

// spin up server
app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')
```