# render complex html in express.js node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use node.js 0.10.12 and express.js 4.2.0

I want to set the `app.engine` to render complex html files, files that contain javascript and/or php functions.

I tried Drew Noakes's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express), but nothing. 
In my case I have

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('qs.html');
});
```

And when I visit the page, I get

```
SyntaxError: views\qs.html:27 25| <p>the hash has to be always to the end of the url, to be well-defined.<br> 26| sometimes when i click to add the hash first and then the query string, the page does not reload and the query string is added after the hash, wich are both wrong</p>
> 27| =============================<br> 28| <button name="hey1" onClick="historytestindex();">history test index</button> 29| <button name="hey2" onClick="historytestajaxtwo();">history test ajaxtwo</button> 30| <button name="hey3" onClick="historytestajaxfour();">history test ajaxfour</button> Unexpected token === at Function (<anonymous>) at assertExpression (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:30:3) at Object.Lexer.code (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:570:23) at Object.Lexer.next (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:864:15) at Object.Lexer.lookahead (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:113:46) at Parser.lookahead (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:100:23) at Parser.peek (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:77:17) at Parser.tag (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:791:30) at Parser.parseTag (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:719:17) at Parser.parseExpr (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\secondtest\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:188:21)
```

I guess it finds syntax errors, but I dont why, since I paired html with jade.

Please, there is got to be a way to render complex html+js+php files with node+express.

Thanks

Comment: Unless I am unaware of any options - you need to realize that in nodejs, you will be doing the server side development in javascript (and can call C++ form JS).  You should not be looking at PHP - unless you want to make calls from NodeJS to a separate PHP application

Comment: Also, the JS for the client side will run on the browser - the files will be served by NodeJS or any web server/cache that you put in place to serve them (mighht wish to cache them on the browser once served) and cache them on your end as well