# Rendering raw HTML views with Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

I'm aiming to move from Jade back to raw HTML in my Express app, but I want to make sure I'm not losing any advantages of a templating engine, so I want a solution that:

- Will cache the HTML
- Allows me to specify a path relative to the views directory (like Jade does) without adding `path.join(__dirname, "views")` to every route.

What's the best solution here?

Comment: why not write pure html inside jade views

Comment: Because I don't want the overhead of calling Jade's renderer at all, or even needing to even install Jade, since I don't need it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express

Comment: Most of those answers are about using EJS, and again I'd prefer to avoid the overhead of having a templating language at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve that problem I'm using the simple [sendFile](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile) method from express response object.
Here's a use case:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

var views = function (view) { 
    path.join(__dirname, '../views/', view);
};

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(views('index.html'));
});
```

Note that you can write the `views` function in another file, export and require it in every router that you want.

The sendFile method accepts a `maxAge` parameter that you can use for caching purposes.

And you're right about the template engine overhead. In my tests, I got 120~150ms faster response times from server, using raw html instead of jade with html imports.