# Different index.html for angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I would like to use different `index.html` for my client.

I would like to have a `/backend` with a index.html and different views (working)

- I would like to have a `/` where I want to implement some forms for the user (frontend) and use another `index.html`

I tried a lot of different things but I dont get it working.

I idea was to use something like this on my server side:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/client'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/backend'));
```

but thats not working

Code is here:
https://github.com/eftz/groundlevel

Comment: Hi @FabianTschullik if any of the answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to simply render content to a template file:

```
app.get('/client', (req, res) => {
    res.render('client/index.html', params);
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008228/2013580

If Angular is completely independent from Node, you can even use `res.sendfile('client/index.html');` for that.