# Issue convert jade to handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to rewrite some code that was written in `jade`. I need to use `express-handlebars` or something else that does not entirely alter the structure of html file. My question is: how to pass parameters in the new version, for example, the following one which is `user`?
The old working version using `jade`:

#### app.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {user: req.user});
});
```

#### index.jade

```
block content
  if (user)
    p You are currently logged in as #{user.username}
  else
    p You are currently not logged in. Please login or register...
```

The new version using `handlebars`:

#### index.handlebars

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

So what should I write in the new `index.handlebars` file and/or what to change in `app.js` in order to display the `user.username` correctly? I am quite new to this so I appreciate anything that helps.

### #Updates#

#### index.handlebars

```
<a href="/login">Log In</a>
```

#### app.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login', {user: req.user});
});
```

This `<a>` link worked in previous `index.jade` file which was written as

```
a(href="/login") Log In
```

Why it is not working in the new `index.handlebars` file? (More specifically, the url changed to `localhost:123/login` but the content does not change. No error in console.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but try this

index.handlebars

```
 <div class="content>

     {{#if user}} 
         <p>You are currently logged in as {{username}}</p>
     {{else}}
         <p>You are currently not logged in. Please login or register...</p>
     {{/if}}


 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that works but I am not sure. I cannot test it because all my `<a>` links in new `.handlebars` files are not working. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Can you please provide more info. Is it broken on compiltaion step? in frontnend (then print browser console log)? May be servers router is not working.(node js logs?)

Comment: I think problem in renderrer, when you call res.render('login', ..) what is 'login'?

Comment: It is a `html` file called `login.handlebars` in the same directory as `index.handlebars`.

Comment: I am not sure, but do you need register templates somewhere?
Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view