# Failure to execute Node JS code on Plesk paanel

Tags: node.js, plesk

When I run the following code on Plesc Panel, I encounter 404 error

This code on plesk panel only work for main domin (for example ==> google.com) but for other link (for example ==> google.com/sample) I recieved 404 error page

> app.use('*',function(req,res){    res.send(originalUrl); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems a little incorrect for your use-case.
Please replace your line of code with the below and it will work

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.send(originalUrl);
})
```

The above code would capture every single request on your server.

Comment: I want to handle request and render view but in this sample instead of view me using originalUrl

Comment: @kooroshrad For rendering html please look into [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008228/5519365)